# Why is the vector style in the PDF export different than in print composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, pdf

I'm exporting a map to PDF in the print composer.
See the map in the print composer

[image]

As you can see, the top map is different from the bottom; the top has 10 tracts shaded in, the bottom has 6.

Now see how it is when I export it to  PDF

[image]

Both the top and the bottom have the same tracts filled in!

Is it an export problem? Is it a layer problem? Is it another problem?

Comment: How have you made your map? It looks like you're modifying the style between adding these two composer maps, so one is showing a cached older version. If you press the refresh button on the composer toolbar then both maps will likely show the same contents as you see when you export them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know this one!

I believe this is a layer problem. Select your map element and under the "Item properties" tab there should be a box for "lock layers for map item" - check this box. This will keep the layer within the map element from changing as you select other layers in your layout.

Does that help?

Comment: Same result...locked it in item properties

Answer (score 1):

I think it had to do with how the second page was added. I've explored a bit and am now able to fit both maps on the same page which is how I wanted it anyway.